# Jmeter - How to test webpage which has communication through http and socket

Tags: websocket, upload, jmeter, automated-tests

I have a case where the User can upload an image through a webpage.

The response comes as socket message. How can I load test this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter supports WebSockets via [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki/Features) plugin, you can install the plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: JMeter WebSocket Installation]

Once you install the plugin and restart JMeter you should have a new WebSocket Sampler test element which can be used for response verification.

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) for more information on load testing WebSocket-powered applications using JMeter.